# How to make a alert dialog with bottom gravity and alpha background?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-alertdialog

I am using alert dialog to create a dialog in android app. I am having one issue. Its background is full white. I want the background of dialog window with alpha (half transparent) as shown in image. Please help me.
[image: Dialog image]

```
View layoutView = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog_image, null);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity, R.style.DialogTheme);
    builder.setView(layoutView);
    final AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: Try to use BottomSheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways by which you can achieve this.

1. **BottomSheetDialog** https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomsheet/BottomSheetDialog
2. **BottomSheetDialogFragment**
   https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomsheet/BottomSheetDialogFragment

e.g fragment_bottom_sheet_dialog.xml

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/lorem_ipsum"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

BottomSheetFragment.java

```
public class BottomSheetFragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {
    public BottomSheetFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
 
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
 
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bottom_sheet_dialog, container, false);
    }
}
```

Now inside activity/fragment, can call by these two methods based on any event like click events.

```
public void showBottomSheetDialog() {
    View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_bottom_sheet_dialog, null);
 
    BottomSheetDialog dialog = new BottomSheetDialog(this);
    dialog.setContentView(view);
    dialog.show();
}
 
 
/**
 * showing bottom sheet dialog fragment
 * same layout is used in both dialog and dialog fragment
 */

public void showBottomSheetDialogFragment() {
    BottomSheetFragment bottomSheetFragment = new BottomSheetFragment();
    bottomSheetFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), bottomSheetFragment.getTag());
}
```

Comment: How to apply round corners?

Comment: It's based on your layout, you can use background rectangle drawable with top edges corner and add to your dialog's parent layout background